# Get Cookies from site not set in flask

Tags: python, flask, session

Is there a way to get a already logged session and use the cookie to parse content with flask/python/sessions?

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, request, session, render_template
import sessions as ss

@app.route('/someSite')
def someSite():
    return redirect('somesite.com') #Here i can access the site using existent cookie but cant parse or store already load cookie


@app.route('/cookies/')
def cookies():
    return request.cookies #I can't catch ou parse cookie to flask
```

Honestly i'm kind of lost in the matter :/

Comment: I hope not.  If the browser gave you cookies for somesite.com, that would very clearly vioate RFC 6265

Comment: i see, but, cant i just use (not store or manipualte) the sessions that the browser already have to parse some content from the page? (sorry if this is a dumb question lol)

Comment: No.  Unless you have control of somesite.com, you cannot control, inspect, or otherwise manipulate it's cookes from localhost.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help man.